# Tweepy: filter tweets stream by keywords only

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I am interested in retrieving tweet streams about the forth-coming Nigeria's general election. I want all tweets from Nigeria, which contains information about 4 major presidential candidates only (`"atiku-abubakar-rabiu-kwankwaso-peter-obi-bola-tinubu-inec"`).

However, from what I am retrieving are the moments are tweets, majority of which do not relate to the keywords (the rules), not even about politics or elections.

My code:

```py
import tweepy
import json
import sqlite3
import time

BEARER = "my-bearer-key"

try:
  connection = sqlite3.connect('inec-2023-tweets.db')
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  print(f"Database connection successful! \n")

except sqlite3.Error as error:
  print(f'Error while connecting to sqlite {error}')

class MyListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_data(self, data):
      new_data = str(data) #
      data_obj = json.loads(data.decode('utf8'))
      data_obj = json.dumps(data_obj, indent=2)
      print('\nTweet data received, sending to db...\n')
      u_timestamp = int(time.time())
      query = "INSERT INTO raw_data(timestamp, payload) VALUES(?,?)"
      data = (u_timestamp, data_obj)
      try:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
        connection.commit()
        print('\nData saved.')
      except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print(f"Error while working with SQLite: {error}")

      return True

    def on_connect(self):
      print('\n Connected..!')

    def on_error(self, status):
      print(status)
      return True

stream = MyListener(BEARER)
stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule('place_country:NG has:geo', tag="atiku-abubakar-rabiu-kwankwaso-peter-obi-bola-tinubu-inec"))
stream.filter(tweet_fields=["geo","created_at","author_id","context_annotations"],
    place_fields=["id","geo","name","country_code","place_type","full_name","country"],
    expansions=["geo.place_id","referenced_tweets.id"])
```

Sample tweets retrieved:

```
1|1666603722|{
  "data": {
    "author_id": "3301724376",
    "context_annotations": [
      {
        "domain": {
          "id": "46",
          "name": "Business Taxonomy",
          "description": "Categories within Brand Verticals that narrow down the scope of Brands"
        },
        "entity": {
          "id": "1557193940978135808",
          "name": "Gaming Business",
          "description": "Brands, companies, advertisers and every non-person handle with the profit intent related to offline and online games such as gaming consoles, tabletop games, video game publishers"
        }
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "id": "47",
          "name": "Brand",
          "description": "Brands and Companies"
        },
        "entity": {
          "id": "1502374025170882561",
          "name": "WhatsApp",
          "description": "WhatsApp Messenger, or simply WhatsApp, is an internationally available American freeware, cross-platform centralized instant messaging and voice-over-IP service owned by Meta Platforms."
        }
      }
    ],
    "created_at": "2022-10-24T09:28:36.000Z",
    "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
      "1584476943512059905"
    ],
    "geo": {
      "place_id": "13e62ac32ad46001"
    },
    "id": "1584476943512059905",
    "text": "Good morning \ud83e\udd70\nThis is a great week to shop for new sheets\ud83d\ude4f\ud83c\udffc\u2764\ufe0f\n\nBedsheets and pillowcases only \n6/6 - NGN 6000\n6/7 - NGN 6500\n7/7 - NGN 7500\n \nKindly DM or WhatsApp 08062407473 to order \nLocation is Lagos\nNationwide delivery guaranteed \ud83d\udcaf\n@_DammyB_  @yay_tunes @unclemidetush "
  },
  "includes": {
    "places": [
      {
        "country": "Nigeria",
        "country_code": "NG",
        "full_name": "Lagos University Teaching Hospital",
        "geo": {
          "type": "Feature",
          "bbox": [
            3.354450897360182,
            6.519118684124127,
            3.354450897360182,
            6.519118684124127
          ],
          "properties": {}
        },
        "id": "13e62ac32ad46001",
        "name": "Lagos University Teaching Hospital",
        "place_type": "poi"
      }
    ],
    "tweets": [
      {
        "author_id": "3301724376",
        "context_annotations": [
          {
            "domain": {
              "id": "46",
              "name": "Business Taxonomy",
              "description": "Categories within Brand Verticals that narrow down the scope of Brands"
            },
            "entity": {
              "id": "1557696940178935808",
              "name": "Gaming Business",
              "description": "Brands, companies, advertisers and every non-person handle with the profit intent related to offline and online games such as gaming consoles, tabletop games, video game publishers"
            }
          },
          {
            "domain": {
              "id": "47",
              "name": "Brand",
              "description": "Brands and Companies"
            },
            "entity": {
              "id": "1502374025170882561",
              "name": "WhatsApp",
              "description": "WhatsApp Messenger, or simply WhatsApp, is an internationally available American freeware, cross-platform centralized instant messaging and voice-over-IP service owned by Meta Platforms."
            }
          }
        ],
        "created_at": "2022-10-24T09:28:36.000Z",
        "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
          "1584476943512059905"
        ],
        "geo": {
          "place_id": "13e62ac32ad46001"
        },
        "id": "1584476943512059905",
        "text": "Good morning \ud83e\udd70\nThis is a great week to shop for new sheets\ud83d\ude4f\ud83c\udffc\u2764\ufe0f\n\nBedsheets and pillowcases only \n6/6 - NGN 6000\n6/7 - NGN 6500\n7/7 - NGN 7500\n \nKindly DM or WhatsApp 08062407473 to order \nLocation is Lagos\nNationwide delivery guaranteed \ud83d\udcaf\n@_DammyB_  @yay_tunes @unclemidetush "
      }
    ]
  },
  "matching_rules": [
    {
      "id": "1575129079472443401",
      "tag": "atiku-abubakar-rabiu-kwankwaso-peter-obi-bola-tinubu-inec"
    }
  ]
}
```

- How do I filter tweets to contain only those keywords `"atiku-abubakar-rabiu-kwankwaso-peter-obi-bola-tinubu-inec"` (or hashtag).

Answer (score 0):

The value of `tag` in the API call you are making *is not a search term*. The search term is the first value in the rule.

This is intended just to enable you to label your stream filter rules. When a Tweet is matched against the rule, it will be labelled with that tag. So, you might want to get Tweets about cats with images, and also, dogs with videos - you would receive both over one connection, but have them tagged (labelled) separately, and you can have the tag as anything you like:

```py
stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule('cats has:images', tag="cat-images"))
stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule('dogs has:videos', tag="dogs"))
```

Using this pattern, when your code receives a Tweet, it can check which rule it matched against based on the tag.

Diving into your specific example, you have several options here. I assume that you want to include one of more of the politician names, but only look for Tweets within Nigeria (important note: only a very small percentage of Tweets overall are geotagged by the people who post them on Twitter, so you will likely have a smaller set of Tweets marked as from inside the country).

I'm not completely sure which of these are names, I've shortened the query, forgive my lack of knowledge, but you might do something like this:

```py
stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule('("atiku abubakar" OR "rabiu kwankwaso")  place_country:NG has:geo', tag="ng-election"))
```

This would try to match

*Tweets containing the text "atiku abubakar" OR containing the text "rabiu kwankwaso", but which have geo location included, from inside Nigeria.*

Tweets returned would be marked with a `matching_rules.tag` of `ng-election`. You could add rules for each individual politician (with different named tags), or you could put them all into the same rule with a single tag.

Another thing you can do is to see whether Twitter has context annotations defined for these individuals or parties (let's say there might be a hashtag or something). If you find a Tweet that is definitely about an individual, it may have a `context_annotation` which defines that specific individual. In the example you shared, you have a Tweet that is about `domain` 46 (Business) and `entity` 1557696940178935808 (Gaming), so you could have a rule matched on `context:46.1557696940178935808` that would pick out Tweets in that same category. Swap the `[domain].[entity]` values for ones that match your topics of interest.

Comment: Thank you so much Andy, this is helpful indeed. The last paragraph is worth checking, I will see how to do this.